# using while loop in gdb scripting

Tags: bash, gdb, coredump

I am writing a script to examine the core dump. The goal is to execute a gdb command using a while loop to analyze.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

#
# A script to extract core-file informations
#

#Binary image
binimg=$1

# Today and yesterdays cores
core=$2

gdblogfile=$3

loop = 3

gdb -batch \
    -ex "set logging file $gdblogfile" \
    -ex "set logging on" \
    -ex "set pagination off" \
    -ex "file $binimg" \
    -ex "core-file $core" \
    -ex "bt" \
    -ex "frame 8" \
    -ex "while $loop > 0 { print this->_tag; set $loop = $loop - 1; end }"
    -ex "quit"
```

This script does not execute after the while loop. It stops at the while loop, expecting command line gdb commands. I am not sure why it does not go ahead and print the value of tag and continue looping. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Braces don't work for grouping in gdb.  Not sure why you'd think so, but whatever source you got that from is wrong -- you should let them know.

If you want to continue on this path, put the commands into a file and use "gdb -x" instead of "-ex".

You may have a better experience doing the scripting in Python, though.